# In MySQLi prepared statements what does STMT stand for?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

MySQLi prepared statements use the variable `$stmt` but I couldn't find what STMT stands for or why it is used. For other variables (such as `$query` and `$results`) have always made sense to me, and I was just wondering, why `$stmt`, what is the history behind it?

Comment: MySQLi prepared *statements*, prepared **statements**, ***statements***

Comment: @deceze Wow, now you point that out it seems so obvious lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$stmt` represents the word **`$statement`**. Shorter is better :D